# Understanding difference between running an in-code time-counter and an out-code time-counter

Tags: .net, performance, powershell, time, performancecounter

OK. The title of this qiestion is not easy to decode, but let me explain you.

In order to set a common ground I am going to provide some detailed information, but this question is meant to be applied to all possible contexts, languages and platforms.

Platform: .NET Framework 4.0
System: Windows (obviously)
Language: F#

I need to run a program and evaluate the time spent to execute some instructions.
Consider to have a main function, there you place a time counter:

```
open System.Diagnostics
let main args =
   let watch = new Stopwatch ()
   watch.Start ()
   (* Calling functions and executing main body... *)
   watch.Stop ()
   (* Printing out the evaluated time *)
```

OK!
I get a time and I am happy.

Now I want to measure this time but evaluating it from the outside.
So consider a PowerShell script that runs the file but counts the time too:

```
$MyProcess = New-Object "System.Diagnostics.Process";
$Watch = New-Object "System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch";
$MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Myexec";
$MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "args";
$MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true;
$MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;
$StartingTimer = $Watch.Start(); # Starts the timer
$StartingProcess = $MyProcess.Start();
$WaitingForExit = $MyProcess.WaitForExit();
$StoppingTimer = $Watch.Stop(); # Stops the timer
# Collectiong timings
$Ticks = $Watch.ElapsedTicks;
# Returning and printing
Write-Output "$Ticks";
```

Well.
My question is this:
As you can see we have two different types of evaluation: in-code and out-code.
I think that those times are different!!! Because the out-code timer will evaluate some instructions that do not compete to the program I need to evaluate. For example context-switches and so on...
In the out-code timer, if the cpu experiences a context-switch, I will evaluate the time that the other proccess takes to complete during its context slice...

Is it so?
Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uhm, not really correct.
The times might be slightly different, but the difference will be the overhead of actually loading your program.

Both measurements will measure wall clock time, including context switches, waiting for I/O, user input, etc.

If you want to measure actual CPU usage (like the CPU Time column in TaskManager) you need to look in the class [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) where you have access to [`TotalProcessorTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx), etc.

If you want to inspect your own process you can find a reference to it with [`Process.GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, you can get the actual cpu time used by doing

```
  (get-process -ID $PID).cpu
```

before and after you run your commands.

That being said, it may or may not be a good metric for benchmarking the performance of a script.  A badly written script that's spending too much time waiting on external events like disk I/O or directory lookups may show it's using very little CPU time, but in practice takes a long time to finish and is actually imposing substantially more overhead on the external resources.